# Where are Meteor 1.6 tutorials?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to learn meteor 1.6 but keep getting stuck because all the examples are in older versions of the meteor software: very frustrating...  Where is a new person suppose to start? If you want new developers to learn meteor there needs to be some kind of practical learning path available.The ebooks all seem to be out of date as well.

Comment: Did you try http://meteor.com/tutorials/? it's all up to date

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with javascript code in general. Answers on SO are outdated, tutorials no longer work. The js world moves too fast sometimes.

For the sake of learning, why don't you set your project to use an older version of Meteor that it was built for? If you edit `<your-project-home>/.meteor/release` you will be able to nominate the version of Meteor, complete your learning, and then upgrade later once you understand how it works.